# ERRor:%android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 requested, with a size of 10%

Tags: java, android, sqlite, pagination

Here is the complete code.. So the problem is that if there are 9 records in the table and by clicking on the ButtonNext , the application does not crash and displays the message "This is the last page", and if there are 11 records and by clicking on the ButtonNext , the application does not crash too and goes to the second page, but if there are 10 records and by clicking on the ButtonNext the application does not display the message " This is the last page" and crash. So thank you for your help I count a lot.

```
public class TableDemos extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        final Context context = this;
        SQLiteHelper  sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this);
        int i;
        TableLayout tabledata;
        private TableRow tablerow;
        View view;

        Button buttonAdd;
        Button buttonNext;
        Button buttonPrev;
        TextView tv_PageCount;
        Spinner select_table;
        TextView tv;
        ScrollView mainscrollview;
        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams;
    static class indexInfo {
        public static int index = 10;
        public static int numberofpages = 0;
        public static int currentpage = 0;
        public static String table_name="";
        public static Cursor maincursor;
        public static int cursorpostion=0;
        public static ArrayList<String> value_string;
        public static ArrayList<String> tableheadernames;
        public static ArrayList<String> emptytablecolumnnames;
        public static boolean isEmpty;
        public static boolean isCustomQuery;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.elevage_activity);

        tabledata = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_data);
        buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd_data);
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonAdd.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4c9a59"));

        buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonPrev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
        buttonPrev.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_PageCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPageCount);

        tabledata.setColumnStretchable(0, true);
        tabledata.setColumnStretchable(2, true);
        tabledata.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        tabledata.bringToFront();

        int d =0;
        Cursor c3=null;
        tabledata.removeAllViews();
        if(d==0)
        {
        String Query1 =  " SELECT * FROM lespontes";

        ArrayList<Cursor> alc3=sqLiteHelper.getData(Query1);
        c3= alc3.get(0);
            indexInfo.maincursor=c3;
        }
        if(d==1)
        {
            c3=indexInfo.maincursor;
        }
        if(c3!=null)
        {
        int counts = c3.getCount();
        Log.d("counts",""+counts);
        tv_PageCount.setText("Page "+(d+1+" of " +counts));

        TableRow tableheader = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        tableheader.setPadding(0, 2, 0, 2);
        tableheader.setLayoutParams( new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        for(int k=0;k<c3.getColumnCount();k++)
        {
        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams=new TableRow.LayoutParams (TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);
        LinearLayout cell = new LinearLayout(TableDemos.this);
        cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#87CEEB"));
        cell.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
        final TextView tableheadercolums = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tableheadercolums.setPadding(0, 0, 4, 3);
        tableheadercolums.setText(""+c3.getColumnName(k));
        tableheadercolums.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        cell.addView(tableheadercolums);
        tableheader.addView(cell);
        }
        tabledata.addView(tableheader);
        c3.moveToFirst();
        paginatetable(c3.getCount());
        }
        else{

        TableRow tableheader2 = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        tableheader2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        tableheader2.setPadding(0, 2, 0, 2);
        LinearLayout cell = new LinearLayout(TableDemos.this);
        cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#87CEEB"));
        cell.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
        final TextView tableheadercolums = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tableheadercolums.setPadding(0, 0, 4, 3);
        tableheadercolums.setText("   Table   Is   Empty   ");
        tableheadercolums.setTextSize(30);
        tableheadercolums.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        cell.addView(tableheadercolums);
        tableheader2.addView(cell);
        tabledata.addView(tableheader2);
        tv_PageCount.setText(""+0);
        }
       }
    public void paginatetable(final int number)
        {
        final Cursor c3 = indexInfo.maincursor;
        indexInfo.numberofpages=(c3.getCount()/10)+1;
        indexInfo.currentpage=1;
        c3.moveToFirst();
        int currentrow=0;
        do
        {
        final TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        tableRow.setPadding(0, 2, 0, 2);
        for(int j=0 ;j<c3.getColumnCount();j++)
        {
        TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams=new TableRow.LayoutParams (TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);
        LinearLayout cell = new LinearLayout(this);
        cell.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
        if (j % 2 == 0){
            cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFAF0"));
        } else {
            cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FAF0E6"));
        }
        final TextView columsView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        String column_data = "";
        try{
            column_data = c3.getString(j);
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        columsView.setText(column_data);
        columsView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        columsView.setPadding(0, 0, 4, 3);
        cell.addView(columsView);
        tableRow.addView(cell);
        }
        tableRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        currentrow=currentrow+1;
        tableRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position=0;
        final ArrayList<String> value_string = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<c3.getColumnCount();i++)
        {
        LinearLayout llcolumn = (LinearLayout) tableRow.getChildAt(i);
        TextView tc =(TextView)llcolumn.getChildAt(0);
        String cv =tc.getText().toString();
        value_string.add(cv);
        }
        indexInfo.value_string=value_string;
        }
        });
         tabledata.addView(tableRow);
        }while(c3.moveToNext()&&currentrow <10);
        indexInfo.index=currentrow;
    buttonPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)

        { int tobestartindex=(indexInfo.currentpage-2)*10;
        if(indexInfo.currentpage==1)
        { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
         "This is the first page",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        else { indexInfo.currentpage=indexInfo.currentpage-1;
        c3.moveToPosition(tobestartindex);
        boolean decider=true;
        for(int i=1;i<tabledata.getChildCount();i++)
        { TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) tabledata.getChildAt(i);
        if(decider)
        {tableRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        for(int j=0;j<tableRow.getChildCount();j++)
        {  LinearLayout llcolumn = (LinearLayout) tableRow.getChildAt(j);
            TextView columsView = (TextView) llcolumn.getChildAt(0);
            columsView.setText(""+c3.getString(j));
        }
        decider=!c3.isLast();
        if(!c3.isLast()){c3.moveToNext();}
        }
        else
        {
         tableRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        }
        indexInfo.index=tobestartindex;
        Log.d("index =",""+indexInfo.index);
            }
        }
        });

    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {if(indexInfo.currentpage>=indexInfo.numberofpages)
        { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
         "This is the last page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
        else
        { indexInfo.currentpage=indexInfo.currentpage+1;
        boolean decider=true;
        for(int i=1;i<tabledata.getChildCount();i++)
        { TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) tabledata.getChildAt(i);
        if(decider)
        {tableRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        for(int j=0;j<tableRow.getChildCount();j++)
        {  LinearLayout llcolumn = (LinearLayout) tableRow.getChildAt(j);
            TextView columsView =(TextView)llcolumn.getChildAt(0);

                columsView.setText(""+c3.getString(j));
        }
        decider=!c3.isLast();
        if(!c3.isLast()){c3.moveToNext();}
        }
        else
        {
            tableRow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        }
       }
      }
      });
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) { }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in your question.

Comment: For what it is worth, there is insufficient information in your question to spot the problem.  However, it looks like a classic "off by one" caused by your code doing some subscripting calculations incorrectly.  Most data structures in Java are indexed starting from 0 rather than 1.  If you want more advice, I suggest that you either use a debugger, or you read [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) and start applying that technique to this problem.

Comment: Here is the complete code.. So the problem is that if there are 9 records in the table and by clicking on the ButtonNext , the application does not crash and displays the message "This is the last page", and if there are 11 records and by clicking on the ButtonNext , the application does not crash too and goes to the second page, but if there are 10 records and by clicking on the ButtonNext the application does not display the message " This is the last page" and crash. So thank you for your help I count a lot.

Comment: I didn't say "complete code".  I said **minimal** reproducible example.   Have you tried debugging it like I suggested?  Have you tried the Rubber Duck technique?

Comment: I searched the forum and I tried several codes and since I read your suggestion I haven't stopped discussing the problem with the famous Rober Duck (myself) but I can't find a solution.

Comment: After several searches .. I found this suggestion in a post on the forum, I replaced
              `columnsView.setText(""+c3.getString(j));`   with that               
                `if (c3!= null && c3.getCount()>0) {`
                `if (c3.moveToFirst()) {`
              `do {`
                  `columnsView.setText(""+c3.getString(j)); }`
                 `while (c3.moveToNext()); }`  
       the application does not crash but creates a dummy page by adding 10 rows with the last record or the first.
       Is there any help!